# Combine jQuery UI dialog code for alerts and confirms (DRY)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog, dry

I have the code below to show either an alert dialog with just an 'OK' button and a confirm dialog with a 'Cancel' and 'OK (submit)' button.

As you can see there is a lot of repeated code and I was wondering if there way of writing this so that as little code as possible is repeated(written more than once)?

I am learning jQuery quickly but am stuck as to how to write this better? Any help or examples would be really appreciated? Thank you very much

External JS:

```
function alert() {
    var id = $('#dialog-alert');
    id.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'ui-alert',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 450,
        buttons: [{
            'text': 'OK',
            'class': 'btn btn-green',
            'click': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }]
    }).dialog('open');
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
};

function confirm() {
    var id = $('#dialog-confirm');
    id.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'ui-alert',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 450,
        buttons: [{
            'text': 'Cancel',
            'class': 'btn btn-red',
            'click': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        },
        {
            'text': 'OK',
            'class': 'btn btn-green',
            'click': function () { $('#completeform').submit(); }
        }]
    }).dialog('open');
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
};
```

Comment: "Is there a better way" is not a good stackoverflow question. I suggest reading the faq.

Comment: what you're after is "refactoring".  Write a function that does the above, but that takes parameters for the bits that differ.  Then your other two functions just become calls to that function.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak! You put me on the right path to finding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to what where I wanted, thanks to some help from @Alnitak. I wanted to have one function that I could call for dialogs and whether it was an alert or confirm, show one or two buttons. My solution is below for anyone that is looking for something similar. Combination of parameters and a conditional statement.

```
function dialog(id, btns) {
    var buttons = [{
        'text': 'OK',
        'class': 'btn btn-green',
        'click': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    }]

    if (btns === confirm) {
        buttons = [{
            'text': 'Cancel',
            'class': 'btn btn-red',
            'click': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }, {
            'text': 'OK',
            'class': 'btn btn-green',
            'click': function () { $('#completeform').submit(); }
        }]
    };
    $('#dialog-' + id).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'ui-alert',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 450,
        buttons: buttons
    }).dialog('open');
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
};
```

In HTML page:

```
$(function() { dialog('alert', alert); }); 
// or
$(function() { dialog('confirm', confirm); });
```